# UseEffect based on props is adding duplicates to state array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

So a short description of the problem

Users can select a radius via the `html select tag`, this value is send as a `prop` to this component and if the value changes the `useEffect` rerenders

The way i am implementing it now, it creates the problem that the `filtered events` are added to `state`. So it keeps on adding duplicates to the array.

How can i use `useEffect / setState` to make sure that previous items will be removed or overwritten and only unique events are stored in the `state`?

```
const [data, setData] = useState();
const [userLat, setUserLat] = useState();
const [userLon, setUserLon] = useState();
const [evtsFiltered, setEvtsFiltered] = useState([]);

// Fetch all events and store in state
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get("http://localhost:5000/events").then((res) => {
    setData(res.data.events);
  });
}, []);

// Filter events based on user's location
useEffect(() => {
  data?.forEach((el) => {
    Geocode.fromAddress(`${el.address}`)
      .then((res) => {
        let dis = getPreciseDistance(
          {
            latitude: parseFloat(res.results[0].geometry.location.lat),
            longitude: parseFloat(res.results[0].geometry.location.lng),
          },
          { latitude: parseFloat(userLat), longitude: parseFloat(userLon) }
        );
        if (dis / 1000 <= props.radius) { // props.radius will trigger the useEffect when user selects a new value on the homepage
          setEvtsFiltered((evtsFiltered) => [...evtsFiltered, el]);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  });
}, [data, userLon, userLat, props.radius]);
```

I know the line `setEvtsFiltered((evtsFiltered) => [...evtsFiltered, el])` is wrong since I store the new events together with the previous events by using `spread operator.` The problem is I don't know how i can fix it.

If someone could point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would map the data to an array of promises, and await for all of them to finish using `Promise.all()`, before replacing the current state with the new array. To remove items that don't match the criteria, you can return an empty array, and then flatten the result with `Array.flat()` to remove them

Example (not tested):

```
useEffect(async() => {
  try {
    const evts = await Promise.all(
      data.map(async(el) => {
        const res = await Geocode.fromAddress(`${el.address}`);

        let dis = getPreciseDistance({
          latitude: parseFloat(res.results[0].geometry.location.lat),
          longitude: parseFloat(res.results[0].geometry.location.lng),
        }, {
          latitude: parseFloat(userLat),
          longitude: parseFloat(userLon)
        });

        return dis / 1000 <= props.radius ? el : [];
      })
    );

    setEvtsFiltered(evts.flat());
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}, [data, userLon, userLat, props.radius]);
```

Comment: This is a nice clean solution although I would prefer [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). I don't really understand why people are avoiding it so much.

Comment: @trixn could you maybe show me a solution with reduce as well?

Comment: @trixn reducing from an array to an array is less idiomatic, we got map for that.